# How do I change a CSS attribute by getting an attribute on an HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to write this in Javascript but I'm a noob.
Already looked for help on www.w3schools.com but it seems it will take an era to find out this simple answer.

```
if (some 'a' tag has this href attribute 'href="http://www.mysite.com.br"') {
    style="display:none;"
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can use CSS `a[href="yoursite"] { display: none; }` and same selector can be used in JavaScript to select anchor.

Comment: Use CSS. You don't need JS for this. Unless you have further processing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply loop through all a tags and hide the one with the href you want.

```js
$('a').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('href') == "http://www.mysite.com.br")
  {
    $(this).css('display',"none");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://example.com">Example</a>
<a href="http://www.mysite.com.br">this should be hidden</a>
<a href="http://example2.com">Example 2</a>
<a href="http://example3.com">Example 3</a>
```

**UPDATE**

If you do not use jQuery then use the core JS approach:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="http://www.mysite.com.br"]');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
  elements[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">Example</a>
<a href="http://www.mysite.com.br">this should be hidden</a>
<a href="http://example2.com">Example 2</a>
<a href="http://example3.com">Example 3</a>
```

Comment: He does not seems to be using jquery.

Comment: Thank you!!! I used the JS approach because it was to update a very old site and it worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 3):

CSS solution (applies by default to all matching elements)

```
a[href="http://www.mysite.com.br"] { 
  display: none;
}
```

Javascript solution (can be triggered on events)

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="http://www.mysite.com.br"]')
links.forEach(function (element) {
  element.style.display = 'none'
})
```

Comment: Using .forEach isn't well supported in all browsers, exceptions include Safari and IE/Edge. Look at my suggested answer, for a simpler but well supported loop.

Comment: It's quite well supported unless you're using Opera mini... http://caniuse.com/#search=forEach

Comment: You can see in the caniuse entry that you referred to, that only recent versions of IE and safari support that. You can't expect all users to be using a recent version.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [CSS [attribute=value] Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp)

```css
a[href="http://www.google.de/"] {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
    Hello
</p>
<a href="http://www.google.de/">Hello</a>
<span>Hello</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should select the result using a query selector. Assuming you want to use vanilla js and not jquery it will be something like:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="yoursite"]');
```

and then loop over the results:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
  elements[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: you are right, you have answered before me, deleted my answer as it was replica of your's, +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

First select your `a tag` using `document.querySelector` then using `getAttribute()` check whether it consist of any `url` or not, if true then `hide a tag`, as below,

```js
var a = document.querySelector("a");
var b = a.getAttribute("href");
console.log(b);
if(b == "http://www.mysite.com.br"){
 a.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.mysite.com.br">Link</a>
```